# Eclipse JFace Wizard jump to next page programatically

Tags: eclipse, jface, wizard

I created a JFace wizard showing a single list where the user is supposed to make a selection. Since the page just contains a list, I would like to enable the double click selection. If the user performs a double click on a single event, the wizard should jump to the next page.

I got the following code so far:

```
 viewer.addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {
            IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) event.getSelection();
            if (selection.getFirstElement() instanceof File) {
                if(canFlipToNextPage()) {
                   //perform jump to next page here.
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Apparently there is no method for the programmatic execution of the next button. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first need a reference to the wizard page where you want to go. If you don't have it already through other means, you can find all wizard pages via this API:

```
getWizard().getPages()
```

Next, you make the following call:

```
getContainer().showPage( desiredPage )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also access the next page, so a more generic solution would be:

```
if (canFlipToNextPage()) {
    IWizardPage page = getNextPage();
    if (page != null) {
        getContainer().showPage(page);
    }
}
```